# adding class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add append with input classes when the length of it is equal to zero (Which i'm deleting them for editing ) But it didn't add the classes , can any one help me with that

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-item', function () {
    if ($('.item-div').length >= 1) {
        $(this).closest('.item-div').remove();
    }
    if($.trim($(".item-div").html())=='')
        {
            alert(1);
            $('#Options').append(
                '<div class="item-div" id="item' + $('.item-div').length + '">'
                + $('.item-div:first').html().replace(/\[0\]/g, '[' + $('.item-div').length + ']').replace(/-0-/g, '-'
                + $('.item-div').length + '-')
                + '</div>'
                );
        }
    return false;
});
```

and here's the html code

```
 <div id="Options">
            <?php
            if (!empty($financialYear->budget_items)) {
                foreach ($financialYear->budget_items as $i => $item) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="item-div">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('budget_items.' . $i . '.id'); ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('budget_items.' . $i . '.item_number', ['placeholder' => __('Item Number'), 'class' => 'form-control', 'type' => 'text']);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('budget_items.' . $i . '.item_title', ['placeholder' => __('Item Title'), 'class' => 'form-control', 'type' => 'text']);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('budget_items.' . $i . '.amount', ['placeholder' => __('Amount'), 'class' => 'form-control']);
                            ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('budget_items.' . $i . '.active', ['placeholder' => __('Active'), 'class' => 'form-control']);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div   class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-item" ><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>


                <?php }
                ?>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add-item"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <?php echo __('Add Items') ?></a>
                </div>
                <?php
            } else {
                ?>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('budget_items.0.item_number', ['placeholder' => __('Item Number'), 'class' => 'form-control']);
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('budget_items.0.item_title', ['placeholder' => __('Item Title'), 'class' => 'form-control', 'class' => 'form-control', 'type' => 'text']);
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('budget_items.0.amount', ['placeholder' => __('Amount'), 'class' => 'form-control']);
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('budget_items.0.active', ['placeholder' => __('Active'), 'class' => 'form-control']);
                    ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>
```

Comment: Can we see the html as well please?

Comment: Check the case of #options in your html

Comment: sure , i have update that

Comment: If you have one, then remove it what will this do: `$('.item-div:first')` to that append?

Comment: Yes , if i have removed all of them then , what will shall i do to add empty fields ?

Comment: NOT what you have, I see that as the source of your consternation  perhaps?  Clone it first to a variable if it IS the only one then use that?

Comment: Can you give me an example please?